# Event repeating multiple times during click

Tags: javascript

A small development problem, first, I declare a div to represent an icon to enter my inventory.

```
<<if setup.tagValue("map") !== 'MainMenu'>>
    <div id="generalMenu">
        <div id="Inventory"></div>
    </div>
<</if>>
```

Now the real code, to activate this.

```
$(document).on(':passageend', () => {
    window.inventoryIcons()
})

window.inventoryIcons = () => {
    const _local = passage()
    const _icon = $('#Inventory')

    if (['BattleAPI'].includes(_local)) {
        _icon
            .removeClass()
            .addClass("disabled")
    }
    else {
        _icon.addClass("genMenuHover")

        _icon.ariaClick(() => {
            window.playerEquipIcon()
            window.setInvIcons()
            window.playerInventoryHover()
    
            Engine.play('Inventory')

            console.log(_icon)
        })
    }
}
```

This is having a mysterious effect, where each execution returns more and more events to the click.

[image]

Comment: You will need to provide more context on what framework you're using. It looks like it is something jQuery based, but please mention what it is. Where is the `<<if>>` coming from? What is the behaviour of the `:passageend` event?`

Comment: This is from the engine I'm using, this information is irrelevant since they are just markings, the problem is that in each execution of the code a new event handler is added to the div, so I need to find a way to clean it up.

Comment: OK. While I disagree about the relevance, in your engine, what is the way to remove the click handler that you're adding as part of `ariaClick`? Just as the way you've removed the class, you will have to remove the event handler as well. In vanilla JS, you would `removeEventListener`.

Comment: I'm trying to figure this out, about a native method of the engine I don't know, I was researching a JS method for that.

Comment: Hence, sharing what engine you're using would be relevant to help somebody figure out how to help you :)

Comment: It's very likely something specific to the usage of `ariaClick`, so knowing what framework would help a lot. As would the contents of the function calls in `ariaClick`. As it stands there isn't enough information here for anyone else to help you